# Raft of downvotes on my questions after comment on poorly conceived question

Tags: discussion

I posted a comment on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18467072/add-blank-row-after-each-record-in-item-template#comment27143275_18467072

The comment wasn't hugely useful, but the question isn't very useful either.

I believe this then spawned -18 rep of downvotes to questions of mine. It was a bit convenient that it occurred within minutes of posting. On some questions, two different accounts were used.

I'm not hugely concerned, but it doesn't really seem fair - I think some of the content downvoted is quite useful.

Lesson learned - comment carefully when a question really just needs flagging for non-suitability....

Comment: Don't worry. It will probably be reversed by the [serial voting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) script.

Comment: Interesting, the downvoter appear to have a sock, you got two downvotes on same answers.

Comment: @Sha, that, or his comment offended more than one user.

Comment: Considering the user you're accusing has only cast 5 downvotes ever, it's probably safe to assume they didn't case 9 on your answers. (Plus there are 2 each on 4 of the downvoted answers, which suggests multiple accounts were involved in downvoting. Could be a sockpuppet?)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi well, I flagged and hopefully moderator will check and if sock is involved it will get nuked or merged. :)

Comment: @Sha, we don't nuke socks. There are international conventions against that. Merging, on the other hand...

Comment: Surely you mean [pairing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415881/how-to-pair-socks-from-a-pile-efficiently) @FrédéricHamidi.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi and SpaceBison - well, looks like atomic bomb has been launched after all... the OP of that question is now nuked along with all his/her posts. Hope a moderator will come over to explain, as it was ~200 rep user with some helpful posts after all.

Comment: Wow, I come back to this and it's garnered a lot of attention. Thanks for all the responses!

Comment: @SpaceBison yup, I [asked for explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194919/152859) let's see what happens next.